# Handling Game Center Notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center, gamekit

I am currently building an iOS app which utilises GameKit's turn based gaming api's. The game works great and everything communicates correctly however, I don't know how to handle the Game Center notifications which are presented to the user.

For example, if the app is not currently in the foreground and it just became the player's turn, Game Center sends a notification which says "Your Turn" and the name of the app. If the user clicks the notification they are delivered to the app, however the app just resumes to it's previous state. My question is how can I handle these notifications, and is their any way to get the match ID from the notification so i can then load that match respectively?

Thanks of your assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `handleTurnEventForMatch`, docs are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no dice here too. The way this works currently is registering as delegate of the `GKTurnBasedEventHandler` and then responding to the event handlers. You have direct connection to the notification pressed, you can only do educated guesses by handling the first incoming callback after `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` expressly and timing it out. This is a sad sad state - please file a bug about this and file a duplicate to rdar://10177254 so we can maybe get a better API in iOS 6. The main problem is that you have to wait for gamecenter authentication before you can pull the user in any game or invitation. :((